# Curtain simulation not following pegs enough

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm having an issue with the curtain I need to make in a scene.
[image]

This is the curtain at it's rest position. (It's stats at the right)
[image]

This is more of a close up on the pegs. I have it so that the pegs do have collision properties at all default values. As you can also see the whole that I've cut out of the un-applied solidified mesh is what the curtain will react to and ultimately be dragged around by.
[image]

This is the result of the simulation I have at around 90 frames. The pegs themselves move to the shape-key I've applied for them, but the curtain itself moves only slightly, and it's the top parts that's supposed to carry the rest of the it along.

I've tried varying presets, ones with heavier cloth, more and less dampening, and I've also messed with the structure as well. Then when that didn't work right, I moved onto the collision sets and tried to tamper with those, but all of them seem right.

I don't have a picture to show you this, but the general way I want to curtain is to move left and carry the bottom parts along with it close behind. It's not silk, but it's not rubber either.

I'm almost done talking, but in case you're wondering, the stage is hidden in the pictures, but I've checked, and the base of the cloth does not touch or intersect with said object.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the .blend file in case you are wondering.
[image]

Comment: You should probably move the curtain with shapekeys instead.

Comment: So not with a cloth simulation? Or should I select the vertices around the wholes and drag them out to the position of where the rings are? I think I see what you're saying, I just need to know exactly

Comment: You still use cloth simulation regularly, but instead of making the pegs move the wholes with them just create a shapekey and move the wholes manually, visually matching the peg motion but independent from them. Animated that shape key, and let that influence the curtain motion instead.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I've been testing it a little bit more and I noticed how large my scene is. Once I lowered the mass down to unusual levels, the cloth starts to move more, but it never ultimately reaches the place that I need. I did what you said, and it is working better thankfully, but not completely. Should I upload the .blend file in case you want to check it out?

Comment: This may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssYemC0j6Ag

Comment: Unfortunately, that was the video I watched to make the simulation. Thank you for the reference though. I put the .blend file in the post for anyone who wants to work with it themselves.